# CouchDB Fauxton login not working on DigitalOcean Docker APP

Tags: docker, couchdb, digital-ocean

I've deployed the vanilla [CouchDB Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchdb), tag "latest" on DigitalOcean's [App Platform](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/).

I set the admin user using environment variables and I successfully were able to curl to the database server on https port 443, not 5984 as a raw install. Then I created the system databases as outlined in the docker documentation.

The initial load of the Fauxton UI worked (using _utils), however login fails on an UI level. The login form submits the form with name/password, CouchDB replies with:

```json
{
  "ok":true,
  "name":"couchadmin",
  "roles":[
             "_admin"
          ] 
}
```

A toast appears "You have been logged in", the AuthSession cookies gets set, but Fauxton won't let me access any function, just redirects to the login page again.

What do I miss?

**Update**

Checked the network tab again, there's more going on:

- POST to `_session`, result as above
- GET tp `_session`, result:

```json
{"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":null,"roles":[]},"info":{"authentication_handlers":["cookie","default"]}}
```

name and roles are null/empty. Then GET repeats a final time with the same result

** Update 2 **

When I query `_session?basic=true` I get a proper response:

```
{
  ok: true,
  userCtx: {
    name: "couchadmin",
    roles: [
      "_admin",
      "user",
      "admin"
    ]
  },
  info: {
    authentication_handlers: [
      "cookie",
      "default"
    ],
    authenticated: "cookie"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the session cookie is eaten somewhere along the line.

In your first POST to _SESSION, can you check what response headers you get and whether it includes a session cookie?

Comment: Yes it creates a session cookie. What name should the cookie have? DigitalOcean uses a CDN. Maybe they mess with the cookies

Comment: There's `__cfduid` (which I believe is the CND sticky session) and after posting to login an `AuthSession`. What isn't there (which I've seen on a local Fauxton) is a cookie named `mujinaSpSessionId`

Comment: Checked: POST returns a header with set-cookie for `AuthSession` (and `__cfuid`), both GET requests send the `AuthSession` (but not the `__cfuid`) and in return only the `__cfuid` gets set again.

Comment: I opened ticker #4597636 with DigitalOcean, see what they find

Comment: Also, can you look at the request headers for your subsequent GET to _session?

Comment: The request header includes the cookie. I suspect something between the http ingress and CouchDB’s http listener

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the cookie is eaten somewhere in the bowels of the DigitalOcean App platform. I redeployed a CouchDB Droplet instead of an app and everything works as expected.
This also solved the (not yet tackled) need of storage persistence. An app is epidermal, while a droplet retains data (still need to backup) with attached block storage.